# String query param to LocalDateTime deserialisation does not work after upgrade from spring boot 2.2 to 3

Tags: java, spring-boot

After the upgrade of spring-boot from 2.2 to 3.0 the deserialisation of the LocalDateTime query params started to fail.

Here is the controller's signature:

```
public Mono<QueryResult> index(@PathVariable String breakdown, QueryParams queryParams)
```

where QueryParams is

```
@Data
public class QueryParams {

    @NotBlank
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYYMMddHHmmss")
    private LocalDateTime from;

    @NotBlank
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "YYYYMMddHHmmss")
    private LocalDateTime to;
```

This code works great in spring boot 2.2 but in 3.0 throws:

```
2022-11-25 18:33:33 http-nio-8080-exec-8 - org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver WARN Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors<EOL>Field error in object 'queryParams' on field 'from': rejected value [20221001000000]; codes [typeMismatch.queryParams.from,typeMismatch.from,typeMismatch.org.joda.time.LocalDateTime,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [queryParams.from,from]; arguments []; default message [from]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'from'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'from': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]<EOL>Field error in object 'queryParams' on field 'to': rejected value [20221031000000]; codes [typeMismatch.queryParams.to,typeMismatch.to,typeMismatch.org.joda.time.LocalDateTime,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [queryParams.to,to]; arguments []; default message [to]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'to'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.joda.time.LocalDateTime' for property 'to': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try, this works for me.

```java
public class LocalDateTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime deserialize(JsonParser arg0, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException, JacksonException {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(arg0.getText());
    }

}

public class LocalDateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDateTime> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDateTime arg0, JsonGenerator arg1, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException {
        arg1.writeString(arg0.toString());
    }

}

@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
protected LocalDateTime updatedTime;
```